# Javascript and Responsive Design

Tags: javascript, html

I have this piece of javascript for my responsive site (See below).

In a nutshell, I don't want it to display (meaning I don't want this javascript to execute) when the screen size is below 480 (mobile phone).  How would I do that?  I tried using display:none for the div that it's in, but the script still executes and the Hello Bar still shows.  Any ideas?  Thanks.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//s3.amazonaws.com/scripts.hellobar.com/511972d9264fc5de88a0b9d919dc42d757a0d2ad.js"></script>
```

Here's the website:  http://www.thesandiegocriminallawyer.com

Here's the HTML (near the bottom):

```
<div class="hello_bar">
<script src="//s3.amazonaws.com/scripts.hellobar.com/511972d9264fc5de88a0b9d919dc42d757a0d2ad.js" type="text/javascript">
</div>
```

Comment: Not enough code. How do you `display:none` and when is that code to do so included and executed?

Comment: Sorry for not being clear.  That piece of javascript is placed near the bottom of the page.  It's a Notification Bar.

Comment: see this http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/loadjavascriptcss2.shtml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Measure the screen width and only attach the hellobar script if its wider than 480:

Replace:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//s3.amazonaws.com/scripts.hellobar.com/511972d9264fc5de88a0b9d919dc42d757a0d2ad.js"></script>
```

With:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var swidth = (window.innerWidth > 0) ? window.innerWidth : screen.width;
    if (swidth > 480) {
        var s = document.createElement("script");
        s.type = "text/javascript";
        s.src = "//s3.amazonaws.com/scripts.hellobar.com/511972d9264fc5de88a0b9d919dc42d757a0d2ad.js";
        document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(s);
    }
</script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xusH3/

Comment: Hi, I tried the above code.  However, it now doesn't load at all (even on desktop).  Any idea why?

Comment: Works for me. See the jsFiddle.

Comment: I see that it works in jsfiddle.  Do I need to place the above code in javascript tags? (excuse my ignorance).

Comment: Yes (although they are not required in the jsFiddle). I'll update my answer

Comment: Works like a charm!  Thank you.  Very impressive.  I've been trying to figure this out for a while.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 solutions I can think of:

1. Load the script dynamically by checking the width of the screen first and then loading the file in an asynchronous way if needed.
2. Wrap the content of your script file in a condition that is based on the width of the screen/document (the file will be loaded anyway but won't run anything if screen is below 480)

The first way is better, while the second can solve headache if you need your code to be available immediately when the page loads

A sample for loading script in an async way is:

```
<script>
  function loadScript(url){
     var js, fjs = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
     js = document.createElement('script');
     js.src = url;
     fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
   };

   if(window.innerWidth>480){ //here you should check for the width (this check is not necessarily cross browser)
       loadScript("//s3.amazonaws.com/scripts.hellobar.com/511972d9264fc5de88a0b9d919dc42d757a0d2ad.js");
   }
</script>
```

Comment: Maybe I'm executing it wrong.  I cut and paste this into the div tag like above.  Now it doesn't show on the desktop site.  Not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: which div? 
I'm guessing you meant `script` tag - please check you console for errors and paste them here

Comment: @user3117275 I found the problem... you should try the edited code.. sorry